# C# catch windows messages from C++ application

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I'm porting a MFC C++ application that communicate with another application. In the C++ code I see a define of type

```
ON_MESSAGE(NVH_NOTIFY,OnFCNotify)
```

And in the OnFCNotify the following code

```
LRESULT CDllTestDlg::OnFCNotify(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  UpdateData(TRUE);
  CString temp;
  short Msg = LOWORD(wParam);
  switch(Msg) {
  case NVH_CONN_ERR:        //It's error when to connect NVH.
    GetDlgItem(IDC_NVCHECK)->EnableWindow(TRUE);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_SELFDIAG)->EnableWindow(TRUE);
    AddResult("It's error when to connect NVH.");
    break;
}
```

Now I'm unable to get the return messages from the called application.
I tried overriding the WndProc without success. I get only the messages of my C# application.

```
private const int NVH_NOTIFY = WM_USER + 2;

// Override WndProc to watch for messages.
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == NVH_NOTIFY)
        Console.WriteLine("Message received!");

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Your MFC application is presumably handling the message in a `CDialog[Ex]`-derived window class. That means that `WM_USER + 2` is already used for something else than you hope. This is surely going to collide with an unrelated message. If you need to use application-private messages, use the `WM_APP + x` range of messages. Also make sure to read and understand [Message Maps (MFC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-maps-mfc).

Comment: Some additional information about my case. This MFC application call a DLL wrote in C. So is the DLL that send a response message to the MFC application using this windows messages. Now I'm trying to do the same thing in my C# app but I'm unable to get this messages.

Comment: You first need to understand, what your native application does, then fix the native application. Only then can you safely convert it to a managed application. As it stands, you haven't understood, why the native application doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Probably my question was not so clear. The MFC application developed some years ago is working fine and catch the windows messages. Now I'm trying to port it on C#. I can call the DLL and the DLL receive my calls but I'm unable to get this windows messages from the DLL

Comment: You have been clear on this, and I have been equally clear: Your MFC application does **not** work as intended. You may be lucky and not see any immediate adverse effect, but you are breaking the rules. The messages in the range `WM_USER + x` belong to whoever calls `RegisterClass[Ex]`. Messages in the `WM_APP + x` range belong to whoever calls `CreateWindow[Ex]` (or one of the equivalent dialog-creation functions). This is your code. You need to fix it before moving forward.